# Extract value from dictionary - modifying it

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been stuck on this question for school for longer than I care to admit...I've done about 5 different iterations of how to tackle this, my latest being below the question. This is for a class I'm taking.

> given the following dictionary of employees and salaries, create an personalized salary message letting each employee know they have been given a 2% raise and the new total of their salary.
>
> expected outcome:
>
> ```
> John, your current salary is 54000.00. You received a 2% raise. This makes your new salary 55080.0
> Judy, your current salary is 71000.00. You received a 2% raise. This makes your new salary 72420.0
> Albert, your current salary is 38000.00. You received a 2% raise. This makes your new salary 38760.0
> Alfonzo, your current salary is 42000.00. You received a 2% raise. This makes your new salary 42840.0
> ```

```
employeeDatabase = {
    'John': 54000.00,
    'Judy': 71000.00,
    'Albert': 38000.00,
    'Alfonzo': 42000.00
}
```

One of my many attempts (I'm realizing now that I should be saving previous attempts, I'm just using a random online IDE):

```
newdict = employeeDatabase.copy()

for x in newdict:
    newsal = newdict[x]
    newsal = newsal *.02 + newsal
    for i in employeeDatabase:
        print (i + ' your current salary is %s You received a 2%% raise. This makes your new salary %d'  % (employeeDatabase[i], newsal))
```

Comment: It seems you have what we call an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), because nothing in your problem statement says you need to store the new salaries anywhere (though perhaps you might want to anyways?)  So if there's no need to store the new salaries there's no need to create `newdict`.  However, if you did want to, you could write `employeeDatabase[x] = newsal` to update the original employee database.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `newdict` in there, you can just use `items` to get the name and salary, and then print those 2 values plus the increased value. I've changed it to use the new string formatting syntax as well, since the old `%` style is falling out of use:

```
for employee, salary in employeeDatabase.items():
        print ("{}, your current salary is {:.2f}. You received a 2% raise. This makes your new salary {:.2f}".format(employee, salary, salary * 1.02))
```

Comment: Very neat solution, but perhaps explain to the asker how `for key, value in someDict.items()` works?

Comment: @CrystalDuck the .items() method, turns a dict on a list of tuples for every key:value. A dict like {'key': 'value', 'otherKey': 'other value'} turns in [('key', 'value'), ('otherKey', 'other value')]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, that makes sense. I have a question (I'm not the best with the actual terms so bear with me). So it looks like {:.2f} can be used as both a variable substitution {} along with the formatting of said variable ':.2f'? @ Diego Magalhães @CrystalDuck

Comment: Yes, exactly. See https://pyformat.info for a great guide to string formatting

Answer (score 0):

Due to dict stucture, you can use keys to change data, so:

```
employeeDatabase = {
    'John': 54000.00,
    'Judy': 71000.00,
    'Albert': 38000.00,
    'Alfonzo': 42000.00
}
employeeDatabase['John'] = 58000.00
```

now John's salary is 58000

to raise all employeers salary by 2% do it:

```
def raise_salary(employeers):
    for i in employeers.keys():
        print(f'{i} your current salary is {employeers[i]} You received a 2% raise. This makes your new salary {employeers[i] + employeers[i] *.02}')
```

note: I'm using f-strings, this works on python3.6+

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) of dict objects in python. I gives you back a key-value pair that you can iterate with a for-loop. Also, by using the String function [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) you can set a variable with the default message and then fill the specific values (name, salary, etc.) inside the for-loop

```
message = '{}, your current salary is {}. You received a 2% raise. This makes your new salary {}'
employeeDatabase = {
    'John': 54000.00,
    'Judy': 71000.00,
    'Albert': 38000.00,
    'Alfonzo': 42000.00
}

for employee, salary in employeeDatabase.items():
    print(message.format(employee, salary, salary * 1.02))
```

the `{}` in the variable `message` indicate the places where you want to customize the default information with the one in your `dict`.